# framework not found issue

Tags: xcode, cocoa, linker, sdl

Upon building my project (a simple cocoa application) in XCode 3 I get this error message:

```
ld: framework not found SDL
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But framework exists here `/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework`. How do I get the linker to find it?

Comment: I have the same problem. The framework has been added to my project but the linker still claims it can't find my framework - my problem is with the LiveSDK.framework

Comment: I have this issue, but the framework is visible in my project.  I deleted it, re added it, and still have the problem.  What now?

Comment: If project contains Cocoapods dependency manager then This link can help solve the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/46358379/2024878

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this for external libraries is to add your framework's path to Build Settings > Search Paths > Framework Paths.

Like this: /Users/MyMacName/Documents/FacebookSDK

If it is something that "came with" xcode then it should work without this addition.

Answer (score 3):

The screenshot shows how to do this in XCode 7:

[image]

Comment: Don't put absolute paths in your project settings, *especially* if you're working on a team.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error - try

place YOUR.framework to folder with your project.

Set patch to framework in config project.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add the framework by right clicking on the on the framework in the sources and file menu and select the existing file. Add the framework after that it is visible in your project.

Answer (score -3):

You need to add the framework to your Xcode project. Literally drag the framework into the `Frameworks` folder.