# Framework not found GoogleToolboxForMac

Tags: ios, firebase, swift2, cocoapods, google-toolbox-for-mac

After I update my Firebase via "pod update", I got error like this :

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/bennysantoso/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FCM-atfcxuircoryufazlomgwfgmvaqm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac'
ld: framework not found GoogleToolboxForMac
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here my Podfile :

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

target 'BB' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for BB

  target 'BBTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'BBUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Does anybody know about this error?

I seek out relationships GoogleToolboxForMac and Firebase, but I just get a little bit of information.

FYI, I use Swift 2.3 and Firebase 3.8.0.

I will be grateful for any help you can provide. Thanks!

Comment: Same for me.. anybody can help? I've been all the day working on this :/ I notice that using older versions of the same library are not using GoogleToolboxForMac and works perfectly :(

Comment: From other stackoverflow answers I have tried adding all the following to my pod file but still not working:
  pod 'Google/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'

  # Trying to fix GoogleToolboxForMac missing error
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger' 
  pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac', '~> 2.1'

Comment: First of all, format of your Podfile is old (Q4/2016). Remove it and create new one using 'pod init'. Use the workspace not xcodeproj as suggested below.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

I had the same error. Once you install the pods, you'll see the following message.

> [!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use MyApp.xcworkspace
>   for this project from now on.

I didn't notice this for the first time and was trying to build the project using the regular xcodeproj file. After I saw this message, I opened the right project and it worked fine.

Once you open this project you'll notice that you have two subprojects. One would be your project, and another would be the Pods project.

Answer (score 42):

**Framework Not Found**

When using Pods, we usually face this issue.

There are two main reasons for this

1. When we open the **.xcodeproj** file instead of **.xcworkspace** as mentioned by izaaz-yunus in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40373045/2024878)
2. When **Build Active Architecture Only** is set to **Yes** in **Build Settings**

   This applies to the projects target and also to all the targets in the pod project

**Main Project Screenshot**
   [image: Set Build Active Architecture Only to No]

**Pod Project Screenshot**
   [image]

1. Select **Build Settings** (of main project, pod project both)
2. Select each **Target** one by one
3. Set **Build Active Architectures** to **No** for each target

Finally clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: is there is a typo, at #2 you saying "yes" but at image shows "no", thanks @Vinay Kumar

Comment: #2 tells what is causing the issue and the image is how the settings should look like for the issue to be resolved

Comment: All others solution doesn't work for me exept : set Build Active Architecture Only to NO for all pod library

Answer (score 18):

In my case all integration are well-done and also did try so many time to remove and reinstall pod but did not get success.

Finally try with below step

> Projetc->Manage Schemes -> Select check box "Pods-MyProjectName"

And get success.

Comment: I got this error when running in the simulator, but didn't get it on an actual device.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to build the pods project explicitly too before attempting to build my project. No idea why.

Comment: I did this but I can't run the app on my simulator?

Comment: After building the "Pods-ProjectName" I was able to run the real project on my device..

Answer (score 15):

GoogleToolboxForMac is a dependency of Firebase/Messaging. Details in the [podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/f543c44ff4693ce9b223116f74cb6d4a0288dbba/Specs/2/d/6/FirebaseMessaging/2.0.6/FirebaseMessaging.podspec.json). When doing "pod update", Cocoapods should set up your workspace to build and link GoogleToolboxForMac.

It sounds like something about your workspace is in a bad state. Does Product -> Clean help? What about deleting Derived Data and the ModuleCache (Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data)?

It shouldn't be necessary, but you could also try explicitly adding pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger' to your Podfile.

Comment: Nope this didn't worked for me...by opening project from workspace worked!

Comment: @JayprakashDubey This answer assumes you're starting from the workspace. See the first paragraph. The answer solves another scenario that leads to the same symptom.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I tried everything you said here, but still, I can't build.

Answer (score 6):

```
its work's
1. select your project in directories
2. select General
3. Add "GoogleToolboxForMac.framework" to the Linked "frameworks and Libraries"
```

Comment: Linking the library explicitly solved it for me. Thanx!

Answer (score 5):

This was fixed by adding **$(inherited)** in the Build Settings -> Search for LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS.

This is understandable, since when updating your pod file for the latest versions of libraries which your project depends on, the debug output tells you where you need to add all the $(inherited) flags:
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS
OTHER_LD_FLAGS
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS

Comment: where to put the $(inherited) should I press + then type $(inherited)?

Comment: Yes, you can press + and input $(inherited) or simply double click on the editable box and then you can input $(inherited)

Comment: This fixed my problem! Thank you @TomV

Answer (score 4):

Go to : `target -> Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags -> remove framework "GoogleToolboxforMAC"` and build the project.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I tried to run it on my device. On the simulator it was working fine. I tried some of the above but it didn't work for me. I checked that I was working on `.xcworkspace` instead of `.xcodeproj` file, so I tried this one. Follow these steps to:

1. Open Xcode project (cocoapods project) using .xc... file.
2. Select Pods project in the project navigator (blue icon on left).
3. Under Targets, ensure Pods-ProjectName (blue icon) is selected.
4. Navigate to Build Settings and set the iOS Deployment Target on which iOS version you are going to run project.

Note:It is same as what you set in `Project->Targets->Deployment info->Deployment Target`.

Maybe someone get benefitted from this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're facing the same error, in your XCode, go to:

**Your Project** > **your target** > Scroll down to **Linked Framework and Libraries** and check if the Library entry is dimmed:

[image: XCode Linked Framework and Libraries screenshot]

If so, remove and add it again. In my case, I had duplicated entries and one of them was dimmed (when XCode can't find them on disk).

Answer (score 0):

Closed the project that I was trying to build after I did pod install then opened the .workspace and then everything builds perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Open the your-project.xcworkspace in your project destination.

1)Open terminal -> 2) $cd /project_destination -> 3) $open your-project.xcworkspace

or just open the file in finder

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "Build Active Architecture settings" for both your project target and the pod are same. Setting NO in both these cases fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had a /bin/sh script that copied specific Pods which didn't exist. This was one of them. Removing the script resolved the build issue.

Answer (score 0):

-I search in harddrive for the GoogleToolboxForMac files, found in :
  /Users/Marco/Documents/iosapps/BomRetiro/Bom Retiro/Pods/Target Support Files

- And then i copied the files to this folder : 
  /Users/YourHomeFolder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bom_Retiro-bsfjbazzzuwmuidqurdmjvdtnnsb/Build/Products

And then for me is resolved opening the project usinf .xcworkspace file.

Answer (score 0):

For those still having issues after all this.
I am working on a cordova project and the issue suddenly appeared after upgrading to XCode 11.5.

Finally I was able to solve it by opening the pods.json file in the project root and remove the entry in "libraries" which belongs to "FirebaseMessaging".
We were not using that and I dont know how it got there.
Additionally I have changed the "Build Setting" -> "Build Active Architecture Only" to "No" everywhere.

Afterwards I opened the .xcworkspace file again and the build ran through.

Answer (score 0):

Worked solution is

- Search `GoogleToolboxForMa` in xcodeproj
- Remove all references from the build configurations

Answer (score -1):

Swift 5 Simple Answer

```
Shift+Alt+Cmd+K  //Clean the project and Run again! 
//if not work restart Xcode and again clean it 
//Its will work happy coding
```

Answer (score -6):

```
    Friends, you must be confused with the exact result, as i was. So, i feel to share the 
screenshot that might be helpful. We all had to be careful that we need to change the flag for property **"Build Active architecture Only"** for **pod target** to **NO** And build, it would not show the linking error.

    See the attached screenshot.
    Screen Shot 1, Screen Shot 2, Screen Shot 3
    [Select Pods][1]
    [Select Targets in the pod][2]
    [Change flag to No][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7mjX.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCwET.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVGKM.png
```

Comment: Do not post whole screenshots, please provide only in-lined portion, my friend.

Comment: This worked, although it would be better to explain the solutions instead of posting the screenshots. The solution is to change the Valid Arch Only to "No" at the project and Pods targets.