# GoogleToolboxForMac framework error

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, swift2, cocoapods

I try to add the Google Analytics into my project, but I see the error:

```
ld: framework not found GoogleToolboxForMac
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've already tried to Clean my project, tried deleting Derived Data, tried  adding pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger' to the Podfile, tried removing and re-adding the Pod. However, nothing helps. I saw all the suggestions from another similar topics on Stackoverflow.

What may cause the described error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358719/framework-not-found-googletoolboxformac/41221449#41221449

Answer (score 2):

To eliminate linker errors I had to add 3 libraries, via {projectName} > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries:

- Add Other > {projectName} > Pods > GoogleAnalytics > Libraries > libGoogleAnalytics.a
- iOS 10.0 > CoreData.Framework
- iOS 10.0 > libsqlite3.tbd

Answer (score 0):

Once you install pod file use Myapp.xcworkspace. Do not use regular Xcode project

Answer (score 0):

It may be case that you have `installed Pod successfully and thereafter you continued with your project by ignoring message` on **Terminal** :

[image: Screenshot]

Now, **close your project and open it using Workspace.** This worked for me!