# ld: library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac

Tags: objective-c, firebase-cloud-messaging, xcode8, google-toolbox-for-mac

I am implementing firebase setup via pods.

My Pods file looks like following one.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# $(PROJECT_DIR)/build/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac lib search path
target 'ProductName' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for mCura

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end
```

Everything is fine with iPad simulator. its running but when I run my application in iDevice. It shows library not found.

```
ld: library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have already wasted 2 days for removing this error & tried everything I could find on net. And `GoogleToolboxForMac` library automatically installs when firebase pod get installed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I change my pod file to following code and re-install pod. It installed all necessary files for GoogleToolboxForMac.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'ProductName' do

  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac', '~> 2.1'

end
```

After Installing pod

1) Change Scheme to Generic iOS Device and Build.

2) After build success you can see libGoogleToolboxForMac.a file in black colour instead of red.

3) Now select Device and run build on iDevice. Follow screenshot.

[image]

Or you can have build library [libGoogleToolboxForMac.a](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75870052/libGoogleToolboxForMac.a)

Answer (score 16):

I was also getting this exception:

[image]

It fixed after opening the /platform/ios folder in Xcode instead of /platform/ios/MyApp.xcodeproj file.

Answer (score 11):

I got the same error and it was fixed just by opening the project from the `.xcworkspace` file instead of the `.xcodeproj`.

Answer (score 1):

*Sigh*.

For my Cordova project I just removed plugins, platforms and node_modules, readded IOS, and double clicked instead of using alt-down to open the xsworkspace and suddenly it magically worked.

Posting this here so I remember that it might be unnecessary to look for a real solution.

Answer (score 1):

This StackOverflow question: [Framework not found GoogleToolboxForMac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358719/framework-not-found-googletoolboxformac) had the answer that fixed this for me, but it was not the most highly upvoted answer. I had to go to the build settings for the GoogleToolboxForMac target and change the "Build Active Architecture Only" setting from Yes to No.  Then clean and rebuild.

Comment: sometimes, most up voted answer doesn't work for you as your issue is different from question given there. So Its better to have more than one option to choose from. One of 2-4 answers definitely works.