# Xcode error: library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, admob, google-toolbox-for-mac

I am trying to install admobs in my iPhone App (written in objective-c).  I have implemented this many times using swift projects, but currently I keep getting the following build error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlieseligman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ThamesClippers-csissodainpbbjenykdyxuutzxtg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/charlieseligman/Documents/GIT/iOS.ThamesClippers/build/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac'
ld: library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am definitely opening the .xcworkspace file (and not the .xcodeproj file).

I have also tried deleting 'DerivedData' folder contents & 'Cleaning' the project and doing a 'Clean Build Folder'. None has resolved the issue.

My podfile only includes the following pods:

```
# Pods for ThamesClippers
pod 'Google/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'

# Trying to fix GoogleToolboxForMac missing error
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger' 
pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac', '~> 2.1'
```

I have tried adding the bottom 3 one-by-one but kept getting the same build error.

Can anyone help?  At a complete loss on this one.  Seen these two questions but their accepted solutions have not resolved this issue:

[Framework not found GoogleToolboxForMac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358719/framework-not-found-googletoolboxformac)
[ld: library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40848656/ld-library-not-found-for-lgoogletoolboxformac)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally worked out a fix:

1. Xcode > Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes
2. Select to 'Show' the scheme that was failing (GoogleToolboxForMac)
3. Select this scheme in the dropdown, just to the right of the 'Stop' button
4. Build this scheme
5. Then select the original scheme (in the dropdown mentioned in step 3) and rebuild

All built correctly.

So it looked like I had to build the separate scheme manually.

Note: To build these automatically, use Product > Scheme > 'Edit Scheme' > Build > And make sure all targets are added with your project target at the bottom.

Comment: Well, it solved that error; however, it took me to another error -_-

Comment: @charlie-seligman: don't understand what you mean with 3. can you send an screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in Xcode 10 when building to the `Simulator`. This is because I deleted the `Debug` base configuration in the `xcodeproj` when attempting to resolve the Cocoapods warning:
`"CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set."`

I resolved the issue by:

1. Adding the `Debug` base configuration
2. Setting the `Debug` configuration value to `None`
3. Running `pod install`

This is how the base configuration should look like after step 3:
[image: Xcodeproj Configuration]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tutmq.png)