# Adding Firebase iOS SDK with cocoapads causes library missing error

Tags: ios, cordova, firebase, ios9, cocoapods

I added the Firebase iOS SDK with cocoapods and after the integration I tried to run the project and got the library missing error:

> ld: library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

And i found one same  [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358719/framework-not-found-googletoolboxformac) and i tried its answer and that did not work for me.

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 and my project is hybrid project.

Comment: make sure you have the right target when you build.

Comment: Did you add the GoogleService-Info document to your project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Framework not found GoogleToolboxForMac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358719/framework-not-found-googletoolboxformac)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358719/framework-not-found-googletoolboxformac and other questions with googletoolboxformac tag

Comment: @PaulBeusterien i tried the both question you mentioned but it is not working for me. After i put the question.

Comment: I'm the same, I've tried pretty much all the other solutions offered on stack to this problem.