# ld: framework not found GRPCClient

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, frameworks, resolve

I write swift language and use firebase. when I wrote code in Xcode and built it, it show error message "ld: framework not found GRPCClient". I have tried many time to solve it but I can't.

Please help me to solve an issue. see the message in picture below. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10w7F.jpg)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Likely a similar answer as [Framework not found GoogleToolboxForMac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358719/framework-not-found-googletoolboxformac).

After `pod install` or `pod update`, you likely saw:

> [!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use MyApp.xcworkspace
>   for this project from now on.

Open the .xcworkspace file with Xcode instead of the .xcodeproj file.

Comment: I add Firestore to my Cocoapod  to an existing project, and am having the same issue. Impossible to compile my project. It's not a problem withb .xcworkspace since I have been using it for my project since I added Cocoapod.

Comment: "Open the .xcworkspace file with Xcode instead of the .xcodeproj file." <= This. Thank you!