# Apple Match-O linker error (library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac)

Tags: objective-c, unity-game-engine

- library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac
- error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

i get this error when i run Xcode project.

Comment: Go to Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources  . . . check your IGoogleToolboxForMac exist or not, if not than add here by + button.

Comment: i add it, but not work again...

Comment: you added this library manually or through cocoapods ?

Comment: i added with cocapods, i couldn't find -lGoogleToolboxForMac, i added libGoogleToolboxForMac.a

Answer (score 0):

I used xcode 8. Upgrade it to xcode 9, lGoogleToolboxForMac is included in it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this Stack Overflow question ([Framework not found GoogleToolboxForMac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358719/framework-not-found-googletoolboxformac)) that describes how to change your Build Active Architecture Only from "Yes" to "No", fixed this issue for me.  But other answers worked for others.