# getting this error after creating podfiles for firebase clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation):

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, podfile

I have just made a podfile for firebase in my app however I am getting this error and the podfile has everything in it. It is telling me Error Message: Showing Recent Errors Only ld: framework not found GoogleToolboxForMac clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I go onto the Pods.xcodeproj xcode project and GoogleToolBoxForMac is there.
I researched everything to fix it and nothing helped.

Podfile: firebase instructions said to put  'Firebase/Core'

```
target 'Game' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Game

  target 'GameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'GameUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

I tried running on XCWorkSpace it ran however my app did not load like it always has. I also did every answer the possible duplicate had. I don't even see all my swift source files(like viewcontrolller gamescene and node files) on the XCWorkSpace for my game.

Comment: Can you show the Podfile?

Comment: Likely dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358719/framework-not-found-googletoolboxformac

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Framework not found GoogleToolboxForMac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358719/framework-not-found-googletoolboxformac)

Comment: I have explained that it is not a duplicate.