# Crash due to missing framework GoogleToolboxForMac following Firebase upgrade

Tags: xcode, firebase

When upgrading to the newest versions of Firebase earlier today, a framework called GoogleToolboxForMac is removed, possibly as it's been deprecated. There are a lot of changes in this new release of Firebase.  This lead to a crash in the simulator with error:

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac   Referenced
>   from:
>   /Users/Me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.../data/Containers/Bundle/Application/.../MyApp.app/MyApp
>   Reason: image not found

Under Targets/MyApp, I removed the references to GoogleToolboxForMac in Framework Search Paths but I still get a linker error.  Following another search for the missing framework, to see if its still being referenced somewhere I get

> OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -l"c++" -l"icucore" -l"sqlite3"
>   -l"z" -framework "AddressBook" -framework "CFNetwork" -framework "FirebaseAnalytics" -framework "FirebaseAuth" -framework
>   "FirebaseCore" -framework "FirebaseDatabase" -framework
>   "FirebaseInstanceID" -framework "FirebaseStorage" -framework
>   "GTMSessionFetcher" -framework "GoogleInterchangeUtilities" -framework
>   "GoogleSymbolUtilities" -framework "GoogleToolboxForMac" -framework
>   "MobileCoreServices" -framework "Security" -framework "StoreKit"
>   -framework "SystemConfiguration"

This framework isn't directly referenced in the pod file and I've been searching for the location of this reference to GoogleFrameworkForMac since but haven't been able to find it.  Does someone know where this final reference is stored in xCode or can confirm that this framework has been deprecated?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358719/framework-not-found-googletoolboxformac)

Comment: Thanks, I'd seen that already.  I've just spent some more time debugging and found the reference to this framework under Other Linker Flags under Build Settings.  Once I removed it and the references to the framework under Framework Search Paths, I solved the problem.  I'm not using Firebase Messaging but might have tried it out in the past sometime and then removed it again.  It might be this reference was some sort of legacy from that and the new upgrade cleaned it up.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is described in my response to Kerberos comment.