# Cordova Can't build from CLI but build from XCode xcworkspace works perfectly

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cocoapods, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've recently added https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging to my cordova project which has a framework dependency on

```
    <framework src="Firebase/Core" type="podspec" spec="~> 5.0"/>
    <framework src="Firebase/Messaging" type="podspec" spec="~> 5.2"/>
```

I was originally testing code and everything on Android and it works like a charm.

However, upon switching my efforts to test my changes on iOS I quickly ran into some issues when running `cordova run android` or any other build commands. They tend to fail with errors alluding to CocoaPods Linking issues. Such as:

```
platforms/ios/Pods/FirebaseCore/Firebase/Core/FIRNetwork.m:23:9: 
    fatal error: 'GoogleToolboxForMac/GTMNSData+zlib.h' file not found
#import <GoogleToolboxForMac/GTMNSData+zlib.h>
```

I have found various SO posts that mention to fix the Search Paths or to modify the .m files to reference the relative paths (which is a terrible idea and far too much work).

But here's the issue, I know the project is correct. If I open my .xcworkspace and run it from XCode it works perfectly! It only has issues when running from the commandline.

```
Installed platforms:
android 7.1.0
ios 4.5.5

$ cordova -version
8.0.0

Xcode 9.4.1
Build version 9F2000

$ pod --version
1.5.3
```

I am completely at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My Podfile in case it helps

```
# DO NOT MODIFY -- auto-generated by Apache Cordova
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'VeociSTAGE' do
        project 'VeociSTAGE.xcodeproj'
        pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.0'
        pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.2'
        pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac', '~> 2.1.4'
end
```

**EDIT:**

Podfile.lock

```
PODS:
  - Firebase/Core (5.2.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 5.0.1)
  - Firebase/CoreOnly (5.2.0):
    - FirebaseCore (= 5.0.3)
  - Firebase/Messaging (5.2.0):
    - Firebase/CoreOnly
    - FirebaseMessaging (= 3.0.2)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (5.0.1):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 3.0)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"
    - nanopb (~> 0.3)
  - FirebaseCore (5.0.3):
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (~> 2.1)"
  - FirebaseInstanceID (3.1.0):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
  - FirebaseMessaging (3.0.2):
    - FirebaseCore (~> 5.0)
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 3.0)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (~> 2.1)
    - Protobuf (~> 3.1)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.4):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Core (= 2.1.4)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/GeometryUtils (= 2.1.4)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/KVO (= 2.1.4)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (= 2.1.4)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (= 2.1.4)"
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSDictionary+URLArguments (= 2.1.4)"
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSFileHandle+UniqueName (= 2.1.4)"
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSScanner+JSON (= 2.1.4)"
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+HTML (= 2.1.4)"
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (= 2.1.4)"
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+XML (= 2.1.4)"
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSThread+Blocks (= 2.1.4)"
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Regex (= 2.1.4)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/StringEncoding (= 2.1.4)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/SystemVersion (= 2.1.4)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/URLBuilder (= 2.1.4)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Core (2.1.4):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/DebugUtils (2.1.4):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (2.1.4)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/GeometryUtils (2.1.4):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/KVO (2.1.4):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Core (= 2.1.4)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/DebugUtils (= 2.1.4)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger (2.1.4):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSData+zlib (2.1.4)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSDictionary+URLArguments (2.1.4)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/DebugUtils (= 2.1.4)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (= 2.1.4)"
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSFileHandle+UniqueName (2.1.4)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSScanner+JSON (2.1.4)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+HTML (2.1.4)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Core (= 2.1.4)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (2.1.4)"
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+XML (2.1.4)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
  - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSThread+Blocks (2.1.4)":
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/Regex (2.1.4):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/StringEncoding (2.1.4):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/SystemVersion (2.1.4):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac/URLBuilder (2.1.4):
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Core (= 2.1.4)
    - GoogleToolboxForMac/Defines (= 2.1.4)
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSDictionary+URLArguments (= 2.1.4)"
    - "GoogleToolboxForMac/NSString+URLArguments (= 2.1.4)"
  - nanopb (0.3.8):
    - nanopb/decode (= 0.3.8)
    - nanopb/encode (= 0.3.8)
  - nanopb/decode (0.3.8)
  - nanopb/encode (0.3.8)
  - Protobuf (3.6.0)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - Firebase/Core (~> 5.0)
  - Firebase/Messaging (~> 5.2)
  - GoogleToolboxForMac (~> 2.1.4)

SPEC REPOS:
  https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git:
    - Firebase
    - FirebaseAnalytics
    - FirebaseCore
    - FirebaseInstanceID
    - FirebaseMessaging
    - GoogleToolboxForMac
    - nanopb
    - Protobuf

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  Firebase: 25ed0412036d7d008568d1fb4d2e9d81ea8a0a2c
  FirebaseAnalytics: b3628aea54c50464c32c393fb2ea032566e7ecc2
  FirebaseCore: a3c87242451633fff8490183898075ce77d168d2
  FirebaseInstanceID: 05d779cbb97bd5bd5c51a38a903fc9cfe1b2454a
  FirebaseMessaging: 6894b8fe0a0cf26c3b13dad729f1131654ae0bdb
  GoogleToolboxForMac: 91c824d21e85b31c2aae9bb011c5027c9b4e738f
  nanopb: 5601e6bca2dbf1ed831b519092ec110f66982ca3
  Protobuf: 0fc0ad8bec688b2a3017a139953e01374fedbd5f

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 6a610b85e4adb104d20d7784dc2566b45be5418c

COCOAPODS: 1.5.3
```

**EDIT**

Here's the interesting thing I just ran `xcodebuild -workspace Project.xcworkspace -scheme Project` and it built successfully. I have a feeling that cordova is targeting the .xcodeproj as opposed to .xcworkspace. More investigation to come...

**EDIT**
It's not targeting the xcodeproj and it is targeting the xcworkspace but there seems to be an issue with the .xcconfig that is specified in `platforms/ios/cordova/lib/build.js`

Comment: Some of the dependency changes in Firebase 5.5.0 may be causing trouble with the cordova packaging.  What's in your Podfile.lock?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien just added it... it's weird looks like there's multiple references... although I know very little about Cocoapods... so I'm not sure if it's right or wrong.

Comment: Hmm, looks like all versions are before 5.5.0, so it's something else. Make sure you clear DerivedData and other Xcode state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Framework not found GoogleToolboxForMac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358719/framework-not-found-googletoolboxformac)

Comment: @MartinZeitler I have tried that... no luck..

Comment: @PaulBeusterien I have tried that but will try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-14057).

The problem seems to be related to `cordova build` command using `-xcconfig` flag and that flag is causing the problems for some unknown reason. It's being investigated at the moment.

Comment: Yes that's what I was finding... I have a GitHub issue open and never found the link/ticket you shared.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would try the following -

1. Do you think the pods are installing as expected? I would create a `after_prepare` hook with `pod install --project-directory=platforms/ios/` or `pod install --project-directory=platforms/android/` based on platform.
2. I observed that the Xcode fails though the pods are installed and everything in place. so, I would try a clean state.

   - Remove node modules
   - Remove plugins folder
   - Remove platform folders: ios and android
   - install node modules/ bower dependencies
   - Add platform folders back.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the lib/build.js will run this command behind the sense:

```
xcodebuild -workspace <app_name>.xcworkspace -scheme <app_name> -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12 Pro Max" build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/path/to/project/platforms/ios/build/emulator SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/path/to/project/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

If I remove the bold code line **build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/path/to/project/platforms/ios/build/emulator SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/path/to/project/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch**, it builds succeed. Not sure why?