# Flutter Error : Framework not found GoogleToolboxForMac

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to run my flutter project and i got this error

```
`Error (Xcode): Framework not found GoogleToolboxForMac

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

`

i have try solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358719/framework-not-found-googletoolboxformac) and none works for me